# Microphone Rehab / Reconditioning

Tags: equipment, microphone, repair

I know I've read stories on here about some of you buying thrift store mics that you take in and get tweaked into great mics at amazing bargains.

The 414 at work has been giving us some issues that lead us to believe a good once over by a proper technician would be in order. Only problem is, I have no idea what kind of tech we should send it out to.

So when you get your super pawn shop bargain or your old standby mic just starts performing badly, who do you send it out to? Back to the manufacturer? Do you have a particular guy you recommend? Can you find someone in the yellow pages? What kind of tech am I looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I like Bob Payne at vintage loop.  He has taken in mics that no sane person would try to fix.  He has also traded for less-valuable but more functional new stock that he has for sale.

Answer (score 1):

When our AKG C12-VR started acting funny, we called up AKG and got an RMA number. They have a few specific technicians that they work with, I got the impression that they weren't working directly for AKG, but were contractors.

Long story short...it was worth it, in my opinion, to send it into a manufacturer approved tech. You may want to contact www.recordinghacks.com and ask for some recommendations to get some other options though.